# ViewPager can not response the touch event when there is a view on top of it

Tags: android, android-viewpager

There is a viewpager and  a RelativeLayout in a relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:weather="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainview_id">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<PushPullDoorView
    android:id="@+id/pull_down_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</PushPullDoorView>
```

the PushPullDoorView have been override the  onTouchEvent method.it can be dragged down and up.But when I try to move the viewpager,it does not response the event.I try to override the dispatchTouchEvent,onInterceptTouchEvent,and set the return value of true or false.It still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both PushPullDoorView and android.support.v4.view.ViewPager are having android:layout_height="match_parent" so only one view will be in contact in the screen. Try to change the layout design to resolve this.

Comment: PushPullDoorView has a transparent background. and we can see the viewpager content. So I want to move the vewpager when it is covered.Any ideas?

Comment: I have found the reason that is I return true in onTouchEvent method.remove it and it works perfectly.